# Why don't statements between onscreenclick() and mainloop() get executed?

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to print the value of a variable whose value is assigned based on the coordinates of the clicked point in turtle.

```
import turtle as t
position=0
j=0
def get(a,b):
    print("(", a, "," ,b,")")
    global position
    if b>0:
        if a<0:
            position=1
        else:
            position=2
    else:
        if a<0:
            position=3
        else:
            position=4

def main():
    global j
    j = j+1
    t.onscreenclick(get)
    print(position)
    t.mainloop()

main()
```

But nothing (I tried other things like calling other functions etc) between the `t.onscreenclick()` and `t.mainloop()` gets executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onscreenclick` doesn't wait for your click. It only inform `mainloop` what function it has to execute when you click. `mainloop` does all stuff - it creates main window, gets mouse/keyboard events from Operation System, sends events to elements/widgets in window, runs functions assigned with `onscreenclick`/`ontimer`/etc., redraws elements on screen, etc.

So `print(position)` is executed before even `mainloop` opens window.
You have to print inside `get()`

```
import turtle as t

# --- functions ---

def get(x, y):

    print("(", x, ",", y, ")")

    if y > 0:
        if x < 0:
            position = 1
        else:
            position = 2
    else:
        if x < 0:
            position = 3
        else:
            position = 4

    print('pos:', position)

# --- main ---

# inform mainloop what function use when you click
t.onscreenclick(get) 

# start "the engine" (event loop)
t.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. But  if I want to use another function with position as parameter after every click, do I need to call that function inside get() or is there some other way?

Comment: yes, you have to use it in `get()`. It is the most natural way.